# Problem with word document while multi-user edit document

Tags: 2013, library, word

We have a problem while editing MS Word that only user that last opened document for edit can save his/her entry.
Example:
User 1 opens document for edit, user 2 after her and user 3 after him. User 2 sees that user 1 is editing document, user 3 sees that users 1 and 2 are editing. But when users save their entries, only entry from last user 3 in this case are visible.

Versioning is enabled.

I should note that this happens in library where we added our template word document with quick parts that are connected with library columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.
Problem was that no matter if we activated versioning, only last user's entry would be saved. So we found out we have to lock a field for entry. Basically, user has to right click on field he wishes to use and choose **Block Authors** option.
Found explanation on this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/My-changes-are-missing-after-simultaneously-editing-a-document-with-other-authors-1cd7881a-c876-486f-959f-4a75c4dc1069?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)